# Constructing the locus of points subtending angle other than 90°(a fixed angle) always with the line joining that point with the fixed points?

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

We already know how to construct locus of points whose lines joining the two fixed points make angle 90° . ( its just using the circle property that from dimater to any point on it , it subtends 90° angle) consider now if we want the locus of such points whose lines make 120°,150° angle with the fixed points , is it possible to construct it ( without using coordinate to first get the locus)i.e. a Euclidean geometry method i was looking for . My intial thought was to first break it into 90+_theta angle and then first get the 90° locus using circle and then make angles subtended to it by +- theta and then connect those new two points with the fixed points .

Comment: First construct an isosceles triangle with the line segment joining the two fixed points as its base and the given angle, say $\theta$, as its apex angle.
Then construct the circumcircle of this isosceles triangle. The arc segement of the circumcircle that contains the apex of the isosceles triangle and is bounded by the two fixed points is the required locus. We used the theorem Euclid III 21, which states that angles in the same segment of a circle are equal, to obtain this construction.

Comment: You could have just write the same as answer its answered my question

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Well, I opted for posting my answer as a comment.

Comment: Okay as you say